# Displaying on different times

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

This is for my timer

```
     private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string timeNow = "";

        timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
       medicineAlarm();
    }
    private void medicineAlarm()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = database.getSchedule();

        string AMTime;
        string PMTime;
        string NNTime;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            AMTime = row["AMIntake"].ToString();
            PMTime = row["PMIntake"].ToString();
            NNTime = row["NNIntake"].ToString();

             if (AMTime == timeNow || PMTime == timeNow || NNTime == timeNow)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Drink Medicine");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i show the message even if i am running the program? Hope you can help me. This is inside my form_load

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.timer_tick);
        timer.Start();
```

Comment: Why do you compare their string representations? Save your values as a DateTime in your datatable, cast your `row["..."]` to `DateTime` and compare them with `DateTime.Now` as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `medicineAlarm()` method does not have any access to the `timeNow`variable that you are setting up in the `timer_tick()` event handler. I suggest you pass the variable in:

```
private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
   medicineAlarm(timeNow);
}

private void medicineAlarm(string timeNow)
{
    DataTable dt = database.getSchedule();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach(var label in new [] {"AM", "PM", "NN"})
            if (row[label + "Intake"].ToString() == timeNow)
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Drink Medicine");
                   return;
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code compiles at all since the variable `string timeNow = "";` is declared in event handler and doesn't exists in your method body. You may want to pass it to the method like

```
private void medicineAlarm(string timeNow)
{
```

You then call it

```
 private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string timeNow = "";

    timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
   medicineAlarm(timeNow);
}
```

Comment: @SylviaEspiña, consider accepting the answer then by clicking the check button